# MIX DIV operator, and Conversion of packed bytes number

Tags: assembly, knuth, taocp

I'm working through Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming*, and I have a question about the MIX assembly language, particularly the DIV operator.

On page 133, he gives an example of how the DIV operator affects the Accumulator and Extension registers, given a particular state of those registers, and the input memory cell. The question is described (and answered, I think) in this Stack Overflow post: [How does division work in MIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768948/how-does-division-work-in-mix)

My problem is that the person who answered converted the value of the 10-byte word stored in rAX (registers A and X) into a single number, using a method that I don't understand:

> If you do the division by hand, by converting the bytes into a single
>   number you will get -210,501,825 (if you're using the smallest kind of
>   byte - which is 6 bits (!) in Knuths book)

Can somebody walk me through this conversion?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the byte size that you're using. Knuth deliberately leaves the underlying implementation of bytes undefined - each byte can support anywhere from 64 to 100 underlying values, but the *minimum* is 64, and that's what most implementations seem to use.

Let's say each byte holds 64 values, and say you have the following register contents in rA:

```
+ 01 02 03 04 05
```

The least significant byte is on the right hand side. Therefore, the "overall" value of the entire rA register would be:

```
= (1 * 64^4) + (2 * 64^3) + (3 * 64^2) + (4 * 64^1) + (5 * 64^0)
= (1 * 16777216) + (2 * 262144) + (3 * 4096) + (4 * 64) + (5 * 1)
= 17314053
```

That's exactly what GNU MDK will give you:

```
MIX> weval 1(1:1),2(2:2),3(3:3),4(4:4),5(5:5)
+ 01 02 03 04 05 (0017314053)
```

For rAX (rA and rX considered as one register), it's the same idea, except you put rA to the left of rX. So if you have:

```
rA = + 01 02 03 04 05
rX = + 06 07 08 09 10
```

The overall value would be:

```
(1 * 64^9) + (2 * 64^8) + (3 * 64^7) + (4 * 64^6) + (5 * 64^5) +
(6 * 64^4) + (7 * 64^3) + (8 * 64^2) + (9 * 64^1) + (10 * 64^0)
```

For a *decimal* implementation, you would just use 100 instead of 64 as the base. So in the initial example, you would end up with:

```
= (1 * 100^4) + (2 * 100^3) + (3 * 100^2) + (4 * 100^1) + (5 * 100^0)
= 102030405
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is fantastic.  Thank you.  These examples confused me also.